# More commenting options in the review-beta for low-quality-posts

Tags: feature-request

Can we have a "this answer seems incomplete, but I don't know how to fix it" option in the new low quality posts review tool.

Ideally, allowing us to add detail as to what may need expanding on.

Comment: My work around on http://rpg.stackexchange.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts/24 was to open the question, comment on the answer, and then "not sure" the answer in the review tool

Comment: I think they're asking for discussion of the new review system to be here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review?sort=newest

Comment: Then they should put that link on the review tool.... :)

Comment: That's where I got it; "We're currently soliciting feedback on an improved system for reviewing posts on the site".